# Delphi XE7 using decimal in editbox to divide

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

Please help:
I have two edit boxes on my form. The first one I use to type in an amount. The second one I use to divide the amount with. The problem is I try a number with a decimal like 5.5 and I keep on getting the error: "'5.5' is not a valid integer value".

Here is the code that I use:

```
var igroei,ipen, iper : integer;
    rgroei, rper : real;

begin
   ipen := strtoint(edtpen.Text); //the amount enter like 35060
   iper := strtoint(edtper.Text); // The number use for the percentage like 5.5
   iper := iper div 100;
   rgroei := ipen + iper;
   pnlpm.Caption := floattostrF(rgroei,ffcurrency,8,2);
end;
```

Thank you

Comment: *StrToInt* means *STring TO INTeger*, and **integers** don't have decimal places. You should learn the difference between integers and floating point types, and use the appropriate functions (StrToInt and StrToFloat) as needed.

Answer (score 6):

`5.5` is indeed not a valid *integer*. It is a *floating point* value.  Use `StrToFloat()` instead of `StrToInt()`, and use `Extended` instead of `Integer` for the variable type.

```
var
  ipen, iper, rgroei : Extended;
begin
  ipen := StrToFloat(edtpen.Text); //the amount enter like 35060
  iper := StrToFloat(edtper.Text); // The number use for the percentage like 5.5
  iper := iper / 100.0;
  rgroei := ipen + iper;
  pnlpm.Caption := FloatToStrF(rgroei, ffcurrency, 8, 2);
end;
```

You should read the following to get started:

[Integer and floating point numbers: The different number types in Delphi](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Numbers)

Comment: Thank you very much. Will use the Extended next time.